# laravel wellcome page stop working on remote site

Tags: php, laravel, apache, virtualhost

I think that i have some problem on how ive written the virtualhost file for 2 laravel sites, that I need thats works as "subfolders" on a vps.

So the result should be something like:

- ip/site1
- ip/site2

My virtual host file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Alias /test /var/www/html/test/public
    Alias /tuttometeo /var/www/html/tuttometeo/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/test>
            Options Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/tuttometeo>
            Options Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>



     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

I have setted all permission on folders/storage etc. and i've added to public/.htaccess of each folder the script:

```
RewriteBase /test/
```

and
RewriteBase /tuttometeo/

at the end of both files, -so keeping the rest of default laravel's .htaccess-

From 'test' site all works!
From 'tuttometeo' site works all route like ip/tuttometeo/link1, ip/tuttometeo/link2 etc.
But the basic route:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('welcome');
}
);
```

off wellcome's laravel page, show a bad error like:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.

In local machine all works good (without virtual host!!!!) even the welcome page, so I am forced to think that ive wrong something on vhost file!

thanks for the help